# How to use babel-node with nvm in VisualStudio Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, babeljs, nvm

What can I do to `tasks.json` and `launch.json` in `vscode` to get them to launch things with `babel-node` along with `nvm`? It only launches babel-node with the globally installed node rather than a specific NVM executable. Is there a way to set PATH environment variable?

I want to verify it by printing `process.version` from the program and making sure it prints the version of node I expected.